# how to override the page being viewed

Tags: cakephp

I copied the pages_controller.php to my app/controllers folder, then i created a view and placed it under pages. I have a custom_layout.ctp under views. The problem I am having is that the view I placed under pages is displaying with the default look of cakephp but i want to use my custom_layout. I tried by adding the last line on this code but nothing...

```
<?php
/**
 * Static content controller.
 *
 * This file will render views from views/pages/
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2011, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2011, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.cake.libs.controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

/**
 * Static content controller
 *
 * Override this controller by placing a copy in controllers directory of an application
 *
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.cake.libs.controller
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/view/958/The-Pages-Controller
 */
class PagesController extends AppController {

/**
 * Controller name
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $name = 'Pages';

/**
 * Default helper
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');

/**
 * This controller does not use a model
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $uses = array();

/**
 * Displays a view
 *
 * @param mixed What page to display
 * @access public
 */
    function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));

        $this->layout = 'custom_layout';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the layout *before* the call to `render`, since `render` *renders* the view with the current layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your controller add:
$this->layout = "custom_layout";
```